# Translate PHP cURL to JavaScript (connect to WCF service)

Tags: javascript, php, wcf, curl

I have a WCF API that I have to connect to. I don't really have access to its code, but this works:

```
$user = "login";

$password = "pwdstr";
$service_credentials = "external_api_user:sometext";

$arg = $user.'|'.sha1($user."somestr".$password);
$url='https://mysteryUrl.svc/projectsapi/' . $arg;

// Get cURL resource        
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here        
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: " . base64_encode("Basic " + service_credentials))));
// Send the request & save response to $resp        
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources        
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
```

And I would like my webpage to get data from the same api. So far, I've managed to get this far:

```
function requestFromApi() {
    var user = "login";
    var password = "pwdstr";
    var service_credentials = "external_api_user:sometext";
    var arg = user + '|' + sha1(user + "somestr" + password);
    var url = 'https://mysteryUrl.svc/projectsapi/' + arg;

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",  base64_encode("Basic " + service_credentials));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",'Codular Sample cURL Request');
      },
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("Cannot get data");
      }
      });
};
```

Which of course does not work. Im totally new to web development, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Chrome console throws this, when loading the page:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" 
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http s://verylongUrlAsInTheCodeAbove. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.
```

How can I set the header?
It seems to me that at least one of the problem is trying to access a different domain, so how could I do that?

Is there another way to access this API using JavaScript? Could making a dumb PHP 'API' that would basically just resend my data work? Im open to propositions. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: 
I used JSONP:

```
 <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/functions.js"></script>

    <script>
    alert('1');
        $(document).ready(function requestFromApi() {
        var user = "login";
        var password = "pwdstr";
        var service_credentials = "external_api_user:sometext";
        var arg = user + '|' + sha1(user + "somestr" + password);
        var url='https://mysteryUrl.svc/projectsapi/' + arg;

       $.ajax({
        url: url+"?callback=?",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",  base64_encode("Basic " + service_credentials) );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("User-Agent",'Codular Sample cURL Request');
            },
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (dataWeGotViaJsonp) {
            alert(dataWeGotViaJsonp);
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("Cannot get data");
        }
        });

        });
        alert('2');
    </script>

</head>
```

And now I get Bad request error. So where the error might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the good path, the error you get is because your WPF server doesn't have [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers enabled, CORS headers tell the webbrowsers which domains are allowed to connect to the server, if the current domain isn't allowed the browser refuses the connection.

For an example on how to enable CORS on WPF: http://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html.

Comment: Thanks:) I used JSONP, and I'm getting somewhere- now i get a bad request error, but that at least means that im sending something and getting something back. More code in my edit of start message!

Comment: Also, my php is in a different domain than wcf, so there should be no need for changing anything wcf side, i think. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, so the WCF service required changes, which I was unable to make, but luckily a colleague did it and now it all works. 
Im not sure if it were the cors headers, but thanks for putting me in the general direction!

Comment: @prawdziwy-sok No problem, glad it's fixed for you!